# Proving A Function Is Continuous On Interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, piecewise-continuity

we have a huge Real Analysis exam on Monday, I understand the idea behind continuous functions where the interval is specified, i.e. [a,b] on a single function, but this question confuses me as it seems like piecewise function, but how will draw it or define the piecewise part.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The accurate graph of $f$ is technically impossible to draw but the following figure tells the idea:

[image]

The red line indicates the graph of $2x$ and the blue line refers $4-2x$.  The $2x$ portion of your $f$ is like the rationals densely arranged in the red line. That is, 
the red line becomes, like a punctured dotted line. Similarly for the other.

---

**Hint for others**:

$f$ is continuous exactly at where $2x=4-2x$